# pytest bdd pass @scenario module

Tags: python, bdd, pytest

I cannot find a situation when pass does not follow immediately follow the module definition for the @scenario decorator.

```
#For example:
@scenario('myFileName.feature', 'my scenario title')
def my_scenario_module1():
   pass

@given(blah blah)
  blah blah actual code

...blah blah other decorators (ie: @when @then)
```

**I understand that the scenario is tested in the @given, @when and @then. But what is the point of the pass after the @scenario?
Is there a purpose to the module for @scenario other than just writing pass every time?**

Comment: The docs seem to explain it... http://pytest-bdd.readthedocs.org/en/stable/#scenario-decorator

Answer (score 1):

I was wondering at some stage too. Here is the answer I got from pytest-bdd dev team:

https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-bdd/issues/279

> [pytest tests discovery](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/goodpractices.html#conventions-for-python-test-discovery)
>
> test_ prefixed test functions or methods outside of class

[scenario decorator](https://pytest-bdd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#scenario-decorator)

> Function decorated with scenario decorator behaves like a normal test function, which will be executed after all scenario steps. You can consider it as a normal pytest test function, e.g. order fixtures there, call other functions and make assertions

[Some more details (scenarios shortcut)](https://pytest-bdd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#scenarios-shortcut)

> ...with the manual approach you get all the power to be able to additionally parametrize the test, give the test function a nice name, document it, etc...

Comment: That shortcut in the last link is so helpful. tl;dr:
`from pytest_bdd import scenarios; scenarios('yourfile.feature')` for example